# UUID and DNS server of client PC using php

Tags: php, dns, uuid

I want to know the UUID of client PC by Php . I have done this via following script :

```
exec('wmic csproduct get uuid 2>&1', $output);
echo "UUID: ".$output[1]."<br><br>";
```

But PHP is a server side language . So the above code only gives the uuid of the server . 
I want to know the UUID of client . How can I know it ?

I also want to know the DNS server IP of clients side . DNS server is explained in the following figure :

[image]

In the above figure , I want to know the DNS server IP address which is 202.40.176.12 . How can I know it in php or javascript ?

Comment: duplicate for DNS server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721731/is-it-possible-to-detect-visitor-dns-server

Comment: You can't get those settings on a server without the client explicitly sending them. Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this information from PHP, nor Javascript.

You might find a way through ActiveX, VBScript, JScript or Flash or a Java Applet. However, none of that is widely used or supported anymore nowadays or crossbrowser available.

As for getting the DNS entry, see [Is it possible to detect visitor DNS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721731/is-it-possible-to-detect-visitor-dns-server), in particular that piece of information:

> You need own DNS server and force user to resolve unique dns name. If user tried to resolve it then they will leaks to your DNS server own DNS server address. Next to DNS server have to share information who asked about the unique dns name to your web apps.

Answer (score -2):

```
> visitor.js is a javascript library that provides information about the
> client.

> Including:

> Continent, Country and city Date of last visit Referring website or
> search engine (including search term) Time spent on the website
> Browser and operating system IP Address Language Browser OS Screen
> size And more.
```

Comment: Is it open source ?

Comment: How can I use visitor.js to know clients  uuid and dns server ip address ?